# How to know the JDK minimum required version for my API

Tags: java, maven, version

I'm writing a Java API where I use many library. I want to know what's the minimum version of JDK that we must have to use my API. In my POM I have this :

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
           <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.4</target>
            </configuration>  
      ...
</plugin>
```

If I put 1.4 as source version I get error (annotations). Like this I can generate my Jar file. My problem is that I have seen that one of the library I use require 1.6 and I'm targeting 1.4. So why I have succeeded to generate my Jar? Does maven verify the required version of each dependency?

Answer (score 2):

All this parameter does is pass the options to the `javac`  You can't build version `1.4` from another but `1.4` source.  Given Java 1.4 is so old, it went out of support before official End Of Life dates started, I wouldn't support it if you have any choice.

BTW Even if you have `1.4` source and target, this alone doesn't guarantee it will run on Java 1.4.  You have to also use a Java 1.4 compiler.  If you don't do this you can use methods/classes from Java 1.5 which are not available in a Java 1.4

> So why I have succeeded to generate my Jar?

Because you compiled the code, changed the version and build the jar.  if you do a clean build, this won't work.

> Does maven verify the required version of each dependency?

It doesn't verify anything, just whether a program it called executed without error.

Comment: Thanks but what do you mean by doing a `clean build`? Is it an option that provide maven?

Comment: You can take a look at [animal-sniffer-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/).

Comment: @user230137 To get a clean build you do a `mvn clean` first. Or you can do a clean & install with `mvn clean install`

Answer (score 0):

This is from maven documentation:

> Merely setting the target option does not guarantee that your code
>   actually runs on a JRE with the specified version. The pitfall is
>   unintended usage of APIs that only exist in later JREs which would
>   make your code fail at runtime with a linkage error. To avoid this
>   issue, you can either configure the compiler's boot classpath to match
>   the target JRE or use the Animal Sniffer Maven Plugin to verify your
>   code doesn't use unintended APIs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have read that before asking my question but I haven't understand what they mean by `configure the compiler's boot classpath to match the target JRE` and I even looked to `Animal Sniffer Maven Plugin` but I haven't understand either

Comment: @user230137 You need to build with the JVM library you intended to run as.  If you use a different library you won't know you are using features which are not available in an older version.  The simplest thing to do is to use the version to need to support as a minimum.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I don't have an obligation I just don't want to say that my API require Java 1.7 and in reality can function with Java 1.5. This why I asked my question. If I decide to use Java 1.5 and then I use library that require 1.6 but I don't know that, do I get error when I compile?